# SQLite: Using MAX of GROUP BY averages to compute percentage of all the other averages relative to that MAX

Tags: group-by, max, average, percentage

I have four groups of people, and they each have an average for a given metric. The following query would yield four values, one for each group.

```
SELECT group, AVG(metric) AS 'avg_metric'
FROM table
GROUP BY group
```

Now one of those averages will be the max. I want to also capture the avg_metric / MAX(avg_metric) in my SELECT statement. Since I can't use MAX and AVG(MAX...) in the same query, I thought something like this would work:

```
SELECT group, (100 * sub.avg_metric / MAX(sub.avg_metric)) AS 'percentage'
FROM table 
JOIN (SELECT AVG(metric) AS 'avg_metric'
      FROM table
      GROUP BY group
      ON table.group = sub.group) AS sub
```

Unfortunately, I can't seem to get the syntax right. (I'm using SQLite.) Additionally, it would be much nicer to have

```
GROUP       AVG_METRIC     PERCENTAGE
group 1      57               45
group 2 ....
```

In that order, but I don't see how to do that either.

Comment: Your closing `)` is in the wrong spot.